# Check two column combination without raw queries

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, laravel, concatenation

I have a code like this in Laravel

```
 if (!empty($filter['term'])) {

        $term  = $filter['term'];
        $query->where('fname', 'ilike', "%$term%")
              ->orWhere('lname', 'ilike', "%$term%")
              ->orWhere('company', 'ilike', "%$term%")
    }
```

Now I would like to compare the `term` against the combination of `fname` and `lname`. So I would like to use like this

```
CONCAT( fname,  ' ', lname ) LIKE  '%$term%'
```

Is there anyway to use this without using raw queries ? I would like to avoid raw queries maximum because of SQL injection.

I am using PgSQL as database.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with **whereRaw()** - it allows you to execute raw SQL code:

```
$query->whereRaw("CONCAT( fname,  ' ', lname ) LIKE  '%?%'", array(DB::getPdo()->quote($term)))
```

Question marks in the raw code will be replaced with values from the array passed as second parameter passed to **whereRaw()**

Comment: Is this secure against injection . I think so as the second parameter will be escaped as it uses binding.

Comment: Also it is showing me another error as 'Could not determine the datatype of $4'

Comment: It seems that parameters are not escaped when raw query is mixed with query builder like above - parameters for queries run via db::select() or db::statement() are escaped though. I've updated the answer to properly escape parameters.

Comment: I've run it locally and the code works, could you update the code with the whole query you're building now? The error might be related to other part of the query or maybe it's sth specific to pgsql